# Bulk 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have +10000 links which need to be redirected in wordpress:

```
error page             301 redirect

example.com/page1  to  example.com/category1/page1
example.com/page2  to  example.com/category1/page2
example.com/page3  to  example.com/category1/page3
...
```

One category only and multiple pages. Is there a way to bulk redirect it via htaccess?

edit: I solved this with Simple 301 Redirects plugin and Bulk Uploader addon

Comment: There are no easy ways of getting this done. You will need a combinations of plugins and multi-step process to getting it done.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said, there's only one *category*, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+) /category1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Edit:** I added the *301 Redirection* and *(L)ast* flags as noticed by w3dk in the comment below. About the pattern, he's right about `[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+` being (maybe) too generic. Anyway, with the details currently given by OP seems to be a good approach.

Comment: You'd need to include the flags `[R=301,L]` on the `RewriteRule` and this directive should come _before_ any existing WordPress directives. The _pattern_ should probably be made more restrictive, as it current;y matches anything that "starts with". Something like: `^(\w+)$`.

Comment: it redirects me to example.com/category1/category1 somehow